# Rails Pusher gem : is there a way to register_interceptor

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, pusher

I'm trying to find a way to intercept **Pusher** like `ActionMailer` does when I'm doing my tests with its `register_interceptor`.

Any idea ?

Comment: Can you not just use RSpec [mocks and expecations](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-4/docs/basics/expecting-messages)? That would certainly work in [our realtime library for Ably](https://github.com/ably/ably-ruby) with something like `expect(channel).to receive(:publish).with("event", "data")`

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try. Mocking is probably the best thing to do atm.